# Is Greenplum efficient for social network / instant messaging app?

Tags: sql, rdbms, greenplum

We are developing an application for *social network / instant messaging* and we are using Postgres-XL in a high speed network including 2 nodes.

We expect to have millions of transactions from different severs, simultaneously from users that every transaction includes joint, relatively big, queries. Our problem with Postgres-XL right now is delays and slow transactions even in test levels.

We are investigating for an efficient RDBMS based on SQL (our plans are not compatible with noSQL) in order to overcome these time consuming transactions. Also we have no plans for data mining and such activities are not our concern right now.

The question is if migration to Greenplum can be a solution for our problem ? if not, do you have any suggestions for us ?

ps: I know the differences between OLTP (postgres-xl) and OLAP (greenplum)

Comment: What about sharding with native Postgres and foreign data wrappers combined with inheritance?

Answer (score -1):

this does not sound like the sweetspot for greenplum (as you mentioned greenplum is currently heavily geared towards OLAP).  i would probably be investigating some sort of pub/sub, async processing queue along with a caching layer (like pgpool for postgres-compatibile backends) and probably even a cache in general (like redis or some sort of key-value) and maybe even aurora if you're planning to use amazon and are adamant about postgres.